# Question in Proof of theorem 11.22 Apostol mathematical analysis

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, convolution

While self studying mathematical analysis from Tom apostol I have 2 question I proof of above mentioned theorem.

[image]

> Question 1: How does author deduces $g_{x} $ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

> Question 2 : why $g_{x} $ belongs to $L^{2}( \mathbb{R}) $ ?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g_x=f\circ h$ where $h(t)=x-t$. Sinec $h$ is continuous it is Borel measurable. Composition of two measurable functions is measurable. Hence $g_x$ is measurable.

$\int |g_x(t)|^{2}dt =\int |f(x-t)|^{2}dt =\int |f(y)|^{2} dy <\infty$ by the substitution $y=x-t$.

Comment: If you have some spare time can you please give a proof of question asked here. I shall be really thankful to you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734678/2-questions-in-proof-of-theorem-11-17-apostol-mathematical-analysis

Comment: If you have some spare time then can you please help me with this particular question. It was posted quite a few days ago and no one answered it. So, can you kindly have a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739195/a-question-in-proof-of-inverse-value-theorem