# Help needed in understanding proof 11.23 of Apostol Mathematical Analysis ( Ch - Fourier Analysis) [Re-asked]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

> Note: the earlier question was closed by community due to lack of clarity. So, I have deleted that question and I am asking it again after making changes which I thought were necessary.

While self studying Mathematical Analysis from Tom M Apostol, I am unable to understand proof of theorem 11.23 whose image I am adding.

> Due to some problem ( I don't know how) all 4 images are posted at last. For  statement and proof of Theorem 11.23 see first 2 images. For Statement of Theorem 10.31 and Theorem 10.38 see image 3 and 4 respectively.
> Images:

![Theorem 11.31 ]

![Proof of Theorem 11.31]

( Images at last)

> Unfortunately , there are a 2 questions in the proof and I have no instructor whose help I can ask for.

These two theorem statements will be useful:
![ Theorem 10.31 ]
! [Theorem 10.38
( Images at last)

> Questions:

1.how did author derived (45) as Theorem 10.31 is not about $  f_{n} $ ie sequence of functions it's about functions , so I can't understand how author used 10.31 while deriving that result.

2.How does continuty of $f_{n} $( I understand why it's continuous )on $\mathbb{R} $ implies that product f $ f_{n} $ is measurable on $\mathbb{R} $ ?

Kindly guide.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2021.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MELVV.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb39K.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU6YR.jpg)

Comment: please check again the images you uploaded. I don't see any "Theorem 11.23" nor a condition "(45)" or anything.

Comment: @alphaomega you are right again some problem occured. Thank you very much for telling. I have corrected it. It's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question, fix a $t$ and then (I am using the notation in Th. 10.31. Change it properly to fit the notation in the proof of 11.23 ) apply Th. 10.31 for $f(x)=e^{-iux}g(x-t)$ and for the intervals $[a_n,b_n]$.

For your second question, (back to the notation in the proof of 11.23) $f$ is measurable and if each $f_n$ continuous then they are also measurable. The product of measurable functions is measurable function.

Comment: if you have some spare time can you please have a look at following question asked by me. I shall be really  thankful.It was asked quite a few days ago but people are not answering it.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734678/2-questions-in-proof-of-theorem-11-17-apostol-mathematical-analysis